# naming convention for two interfaces for one object

Tags: java, interface, coding-style

I am working on a project to develop a poker bot, I have to store the state of every hand that is played. I wanted to do this via an object - however `Players` can only read from the state and the `Dealer` is allowed to write to the state. I thought a good way to solve this would be to make the `HandState` object implement 2 interfaces (one for Players and one for the Dealer) however I am having trouble naming them as I cant think of logical names other than IHandState - is there some kind of convention to deal with these things? Has anyone experienced something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PlayerStateHandler` and `DealerStateHandler`

As a convention, my Interfaces either contain `-er` or `-able`

Answer (score 3):

`PlayerActions` and `DealerActions`

or

`PlayerAware` and `DealerAware`

Comment: I prefer the `actions` versions of the interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

What about `DealerState` and `PlayerState`?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your problem, not your question: Prefer composition over inheritance (including of inheritance of interface).

Also I get the impression that you have poor encapsulation by using getters and setters, instead of meaningful operations. If you get improve the abstractions, things should become clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You have one state object, name it's class `HandState`.

Make it implement the two interfaces. Call them `IWriteable` and `IReadable`

Then create the player, it has access to an object of type `HandState`, however accesses it through the `IReadable` interface. Similarly, the dealer, it accesses the `HandState` through the `IWriteable` Interface.

Answer (score -1):

uasually interface will have an adjective names. so i prefer **IStateable**